# Calculating the mean analytically in R

Tags: r, mean, expected-value

I would like to calculate the mean analytically (by integration) of a random variable $X$ in R. The formula for the expected value is:

$$
E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  xf_N(x)dx
$$
Assume that $X \sim f_N(x_i|\mu=50, \sigma=1)$. I code this up in R in the following way:

> `my.mean.function <- function(X, MEAN){   X*dnorm(X, mean = 50 , sd=1) }`

I then calculate the integral:

```
integrate(f= my.mean.function, lower =-Inf, upper = Inf)
```

However, this integral is not producing the expectation 50. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to sort it! and one more mistake ... my.mean.function <- function(X){   X=sort(X);X*dnorm(X, mean = 2 , sd=1) }
integrate(f= my.mean.function, lower =-10, upper = 10). Just change the parameter to yours.

Comment: Thanks for this. @Matteo Lisi's solution works without sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong as far as I can tell. I think the problem is that your integrand is approximately zero almost everywhere except for a small range around 50. From `?integrate`

> If the function is approximately constant (in particular, zero) over
>   nearly all its range it is possible that the result and error estimate
>   may be seriously wrong.

Indeed `integrate` gets it correctly if the proportion of values over which the integrand is approximately zero is reduced, either by reducing the range of integration or alternatively by increasing the standard deviation.

Specifically, while this fail:

```
> integrate(function(x){x*dnorm(x,mean=50,sd=1)}, -Inf, Inf)
9.385682e-98 with absolute error < 0
```

these two gets it correctly:

```
> integrate(function(x){x*dnorm(x,mean=50,sd=5)}, -Inf, Inf)
50 with absolute error < 0.0037
> integrate(function(x){x*dnorm(x,mean=50,sd=1)}, -100, 100)
50 with absolute error < 1.6e-05
```

Comment: One would not think that the integrate function had this quirkiness. Helps to read the manual.